# как изменить цвет текста

Tags: android

[image: Хочу изменить цвет на белый]

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="@string/action_settings"
    />`

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    style="@style/Widget.MyApp.Toolbar.Solid"/>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.Toolbar.Solid" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_color</item>
    <item name="android:elevation" tools:ignore="NewApi">4dp</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">...</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Parent theme sets colorControlNormal to textColorPrimary. -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/actionbar_title_text</item>
</style>
```